# How to store H2 database file in Play production mode?

Tags: playframework, h2, playframework-2.3

I’m using Play 2.3 with a H2 file database. I use the default configuration from application.conf with

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:file:data/db"
```

When I run Play in Development mode, the database is saved in `data/db.h2.db`. However, when I run Play in Production mode (from the same folder), it does not write to the `data/` folder, but only to `target/universal/stage/data/`. This is a generated folder though that can get overwritten easily. Also, on `activator clean`, it simply erases everything in the target folder, together with the database.

Is this really the correct behavior? What can I do to store the database in a safer place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **absolute** path on filesystem instead of relative, i.e.:

```
jdbc:h2:/data/db
```

See another possibilities in [cheatsheet](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html) and/or [preview of databse URLs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url)

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. I am wondering though, whether there is a way to reference the project directory somehow. I would like to keep the application.conf file the same on my local and server environments. If I use absolute paths, I need different paths on the different environments, I guess.